# Store full URL including #bookmark in it

Tags: php, url

i have a URL like:

`http://localhost/myproject/contact-us#feedback`

i want to store full URL in a variable including `#feedback`.

How to do this???

Comment: you can't do that because browser not send the fragment identifier to the server.

Comment: Where to store? in database?

Comment: The `#feedback` part is never sent to the server.

Comment: @AwaisQarni in a $variable.

Comment: How about using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php ?

Comment: @AwaisQarni — The question is asking how to store it, you don't need to parse it in order to store it, only if you want to manipulate it in interesting but sane ways.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the answer:

fetching the URL using JS like:

`var url = location.href;`

Thank you every one for suggestions :)

Comment: That's not PHP though, it's JavaScript.

Comment: @Jack yeah man i know thats why i wrote JS in answer.

Comment: My point is that the question is tagged as "php".

Comment: @Jack i was suppose to find the answer in PHP but didn't get it and also its not possible......

Comment: It's possible, as described in the accepted answer of the duplicate question I've found.

Comment: @Jack if you can see your answer, there is also JS used in it..

Comment: Yes, but that's not my point; your question is obsolete and the best action is to basically remove it, because it has been answered before.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the URL including `#feedback` with JavaScript and store it in your database via Ajax.